# Codeigniter - prevent added space on the select statement

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to prevent auto fix in the select statement using CodeIgniter 3?

Query that I want: `SELECT REPLACE(item, ',', '') AS item` (without space)

**I tried** : `$this->db->select("replace(item, ',', '') AS item",  FALSE);`

**Result** : `SELECT REPLACE(item, ', ', '') AS item` (CI added a space in my query)

I read [this documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select) but it didn't work.

This my real query:

```
$this->db->select("a.unit_id"); 
$this->db->select("replace(c.topik, ',', '') AS topik",  FALSE); //this my problem (added space which shouldnt)
$this->db->select("COUNT(*) AS jumlah");
$this->db->from('opub_kliping a');
$this->db->join('opub_media b','a.media_id = b.organisasi_id');
$this->db->join('opub_tag c','a.id = c.kliping_id');
if(!empty($data['keyword']))$this->db->where("(a.judul LIKE '%".$data['keyword']."%' OR a.text LIKE '%".$data['keyword']."')");
if(!empty($data['tgl1']))$this->db->where("a.tanggal >=",$data['tgl1']);
if(!empty($data['tgl2']))$this->db->where("a.tanggal <=",$data['tgl2']);
if(!empty($data['unit']))$this->db->where("a.unit_id ",$data['unit']);
if(!empty($data['media']))$this->db->where("a.media_id ",$data['media']);
if(!empty($data['jenis']))$this->db->where("a.jenis_id ",$data['jenis']);
if(!empty($data['tone']))$this->db->where("a.karakter ",$data['tone']);
if(!empty($data['topik']))
{
    $qTopik = array();
    $expTopik = explode(',', $data['topik']);
    foreach($expTopik as $t)
    {
        if(!empty($t))
        {
            $qTopik[] = "c.topik LIKE '%$t%'";
        }
    }
    if(!empty($qTopik))
    {
        $qTopiks = implode(",", $qTopik);
        $this->db->where($qTopiks);
    }
}
$this->db->where('a.unit_id !=', 0);
$this->db->where('c.topik !=', NULL); 
$this->db->where('c.topik !=', '');
$this->db->group_by("a.unit_id");
$this->db->group_by("replace(c.topik, ',', '')", FALSE); //this produce correct query (without adding space)
$this->db->order_by('a.unit_id', 'ASC');
$this->db->order_by('jumlah', 'DESC');

$q= $this->db->get();
```

Comment: you can use $this->db->query("SELECT REPLACE(item, ',', '') AS item...your full query");

Comment: yes, absolutly i can use query(). but i am struggle to use query builder. because i have many clause in that real query. on above i just cut it to become more simple to understand.

Comment: add full query in your question

Comment: done. i add my full query

Answer (score 0):

change 4 lines of your query

```
$this->db->select("a.unit_id,replace(c.topik, ',', '') AS topik,COUNT(*) AS jumlah")->from('opub_kliping a');
$this->db->join('opub_media b','a.media_id = b.organisasi_id');
```

Comment: sorry for late reply. Thats produce this `SELECT "a"."unit_id" FROM "opub_kliping" "a" JOIN "opub_media" "b" ON "a"."media_id" = "b"."organisasi_id" JOIN "opub_tag" "c" ON "a"."id" = "c"."kliping_id" WHERE "a"."tanggal" >= '2017-01-09' AND "a"."tanggal" <= '2017-01-12' AND "a"."unit_id" !=0 AND "c"."topik" IS NOT NULL AND "c"."topik" != '' GROUP BY "a"."unit_id", replace(c.topik, ',', '') ORDER BY "a"."unit_id" ASC, "jumlah" DESC` which return error: Invalid column name 'jumlah'.

Answer (score 0):

i found this after tried some experiment

`$this->db->select(array('REPLACE(c.topik', "','", "'') AS topik"), false);`

seems little hack maybe. but its work for me
hope will help others